# can I get the correct format

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

- I am new to extjs

  - my fiddle doesn't solve the problem if i have a currency
  - if I want to format the amount according to a particular currency, I
    need to get the format for it.
  - with my moneycolumn, I have a store which contains currency codes,
    currency symbol and amount format.
  - since I cannot use the moneycolumn, I am looking to see what if there
    is something else that can be used to help us format the amount if I
    pass it a currency code
  - the fiddle that I provided, I have to pass it the format which is
    good but how can I get the correct format
  - providing my code below..
  - it would be great if you guys provide some inputs...

http://jsfiddle.net/yy77ja65/

```
{
    text : "Number without dots",
    flex : 2,
    dataIndex : "numberwithoutdots",
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('€ 0')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom renderer

```
function renderMoney(value,b,records){
    return Ext.util.Format.number(value, records.data.currency + ' ' + records.data.format)                        
}
...
{
    text : "Number with dots",     
    flex : 1,
    dataIndex : "numberwithdots",
    renderer: renderMoney
}
....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/yy77ja65/2/